# How to add php on a nextjs project on a specific folder or route

Tags: php, reactjs, directory, next.js

I'm trying to add **PHP** to my **NextJS** project and I'm trying to put it in a folder called **admin**. So it goes to `/admin`, right? But I get a `404` error, I understand that because I don't have `index.js`, is there a way to make it work? There is `index.php` in the **admin folder**.

**Note: I'm on the server**, Also, if you need additional information, feel free to leave a comment. I will do my best to give them.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use PHP? Couldn't you convert the page to React with server-side rendering?

Comment: theres a reason because i just downloaded a php project on codecanyon and im trying to implement it on my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up in your `Nginx` server instead of in `nextjs` app.

Steps:

- Download nginx in your server & install (sudo apt get nginx)
- host nextjs in one port and host php in another port
- configure `nginx` accordingly.

In nginx configuration:

```sh
server {
   server_name your-domain.com;
   listen 80;
   location / {
         proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   }
   location /admin {
         proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }
}
```

*In here, I suppose your php host on 8080 port and nextjs app host on 3000 port.*

By doing this, you can redirect to two different local server/ports.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me, and I understand what you're trying to do, and it's actually kind of smart, but I have a lot of websites on one server I can't use nginx because im using Hestia and maybe all the server is ruined if i set nginx up. I'm just taking a bit of precautions. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Using Hestia you can edit each domain nginx conf file independently from others. Create a new php-fpm template in /usr/local/hestia/data/templates/web/nginx/php-fpm/ and use that template for the Web Template under Advanced Options in the admin.

Comment: Is it possible for me to create few specific urls in nextjs . For example  `www.your-domain.com/about-us` , `www.your-domain.com/contact-us` etc  All other existing urls should stay in php itself

Comment: Yes @Ajith, you can achieve this by adding two more locations `/about-us` and `/contact-us` and create a page in nextjs with same name. `location /about-us {
         proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   }
   location /contact-us {
         proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   }`

Comment: @PradipDhakal What if I have hundreds of pages? Do I need to add location for all?

Comment: No For that you can create a sub location like: `location /nextjs` and redirect all those traffic to nextjs api.